# How to remove the "Text Overlap" comment from arxiv

Tags: arxiv

Recently I have submitted an article in arxiv. But unfortunately, an indication of text overlap has been added in the comment section. It is to be noted that, the overlapped paper is also my other paper. Now I would like to remove that comment ("Text overlap"). Can I remove this comment by replacing this paper with a revised and corrected copy?

Comment: "Text overlap" is officially not a bad thing, so I suggest you do not try to remove the notice.  The appeal process is given here: https://arxiv.org/help/overlap

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist I guess this depends on whether it overlaps with your own or someone else's paper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, updating the paper will remove the comment. (From the new version - it will still be there with the old version.)

Note that https://arxiv.org/help/overlap (linked by AnonymousPhysicist) also lists ways to avoid having such a comment added, by proactively pointing out the related work.